# scikit learn Value error in target(y parameter)

Tags: python, nlp, scikit-learn

i`m trying to classify my text data with tfidf and naive bayes classifier

```
cls = MultinomialNB()
vec = TfidfVectorizer(input='file', analyzer=word_tokenize, stop_words=stop_w, use_idf=False)
for i, filename in enumerate(files):

    with codecs.open(filename, encoding='utf8') as f:
        bow = vec.fit_transform(f)

        # and i have one target for this bow. (each file has unique subject)
        y = np.array([repeat(i, times=41253)])
        cls.fit(bow, y)
```

bow.shape output is like this

```
(41253, 15987)
```

but got this exception

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/PycharmProjects/PWC/naiive.py", line 35, in <module>
    cls.fit(bow, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 522, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 516, in check_X_y
    check_consistent_length(X, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 176, in check_consistent_length
    "%s" % str(uniques))
ValueError: Found arrays with inconsistent numbers of samples: [    1 41253]
```

i know something is wrong with my y size/shape but i dont know how should i fix it
and is my y implementation correct at first place?

Comment: please always give the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Answer (score 0):

That line should be:

```
y = repeat(i, times=41253)
```

Remove that additional semicolons and np.array() call.

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/x/PycharmProjects/PWC/naiive.py", line 35, in <module>
    cls.fit(bow, y)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/naive_bayes.py", line 522, in fit
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, 'csr')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 511, in check_X_y
    y = column_or_1d(y, warn=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sklearn/utils/validation.py", line 547, in column_or_1d
    raise ValueError("bad input shape {0}".format(shape))
ValueError: bad input shape ()`